# How to cleanly remove a directory that contains a .gitignore and may contain transient ignored files?

Tags: git, gitignore

Consider the following layout:

```
tests/
    Vendor/
        Product/
            Module/
                db/
                    .gitignore
                    file-created-by-test-runs-and-ignored-by-gitignore-above.json
                SomeTest.php
                OtherTest.php
```

On a long-winded topic branch, we want to reorganize the tests to move most of the above under `tests\unit` and also to move the location of temporary files somewhere else to keep them out of versioned source tree.

We boldly bring the tree to the desired state:

```
tests/
    unit/
        Vendor/
            Product/
                Module/
                    SomeTest.php
                    OtherTest.php
```

... and after refactoring the test base classes to use /tmp or whatever, we commit in good faith.

Then we checkout the master branch again, do some work and run the master branch's version of the test suite.

Then we check out the topic branch, and suddenly we have the temporary files left over from master branch test runs, under `tests/Vendor/Product/Module/db`, listed as untracked files. They are not ignored now, because the `.gitignore` files (which *were* versioned) were deleted by checkout of the topic branch, *but files ignored by those `.gitignore` files obviously weren't*.

Is there a recommended practice for avoiding this annoyance and effectively expressing the intention, "Hey git, this commit **deletes** this directory; it makes it **gone**. We don't want it, or anything in it, to exist since this commit until we change our mind again."? I bring the tree to the desired state and I commit. I expect that to stick. Can it be achieved?

Comment: It wouldn't help remove the unwanted files, but if you moved `.gitignore` to the root of your project and had a transitional period where both locations were ignored, you could avoid the annoyance of having the untracked files.

Answer (score 3):

> "Hey git, this commit deletes this directory; it makes it gone.

Git doesn't track directories, only files. It doesn't know that you deleted a directory, only that you deleted files in it.

You can alter your build file to clean up the offending files in the old location. Or perhaps you can leave the `.gitignore` in the old location. But this is a bunch of work for a branch which should not live long. And these are permanent code changes for a temporary situation.

You could write a [post-checkout hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) which deletes the `db` directory if you're only on this particular branch. This has the merit of being easy to delete once you're done with the branch. But, again, it probably isn't not worth the effort for a topic branch that should be merged soon anyway.

The best practice when making sweeping changes like this is to do as little as you can and merge the branch. This avoids many problems with the files in your topic branch diverging from your master. You're seeing only one. More problems will arise as commits are added to the master branch which assume the old layout.